# ptrace fails when injecting code into old ELF binary (2005)

Tags: c++, c, linux, process, reverse-engineering

I have a very old gameserver file for a video-game that became obsolete years ago (more than a decade and a half has passed since then). A lot of clones and reverse-engineered copycats of this engine exist, but nothing will ever be like the real thing, or at least without tons and tons of work (it's a MMORPG server). It's so old that it uses LinuxThreads instead of NPTL, and uses it for its thread-per-connection architecture (up to 1100 simmultaneos connections interacting with a huge 2D tilebased game world).

I was trying to rewrite it from scratch, since it has ancient GCC debug info available, but had to drop it since the amount of work to do was insane. Now I'm trying to inject new functionality into it, but couldn't proggress any further since I don't really understand how I'm supposed to inject into it.

I've tried coding a very simple injector using ptrace, but the server dies because of a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) and since I can't attach GDB, I don't really know where the crash is happening.

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define EMPTY_ADDR 0x80EF000UL

const char *SHELLCODE = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90";

pid_t GamePID;

void GetGamePID() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("/home/bob/lock.pid", "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        printf(":: [Error] Game not running.\n");
        return;
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &GamePID);
}

int main() {
    GetGamePID();
    if (!GamePID)
        return 0;

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, GamePID, NULL, NULL)) {
        printf(":: [Error] Cannot attach.\n");
        printf(":: # Fail %d: %s.\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }

    siginfo_t info;
    waitid(P_PID, GamePID, &info, WSTOPPED);

    printf(":: [Info] Attach on PID %d.\n", GamePID);

    struct user_regs_struct oldregs, regs;
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, GamePID, NULL, &oldregs)) {
        printf(":: [Error] Cannot save registers (Fail %d).\n", errno);
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, GamePID, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }
    
    unsigned long save[2];
    save[0] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, GamePID, (void *)(EMPTY_ADDR), NULL);
    save[1] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, GamePID, (void *)(EMPTY_ADDR + 8UL), NULL);

    size_t payload_size = strlen(SHELLCODE);
    uint64_t *payload = (uint64_t *)SHELLCODE;

    printf("[*] Injecting payload at address 0x%lx.\n", EMPTY_ADDR);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < payload_size; i += 8, payload++) {
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, GamePID, EMPTY_ADDR + i, *payload) < 0) {
            printf(":: [Error] Failed to PTRACE_POKETEXT: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    regs = oldregs;
    regs.rip = EMPTY_ADDR;
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, GamePID, NULL, &regs)) {
        printf(":: [Error] Cannot modify registers.\n");
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, GamePID, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, GamePID, NULL, NULL)) {
        printf(":: [Error] Cannot run shellcode.\n");
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, GamePID, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    waitid(P_PID, GamePID, &info, WSTOPPED);

    // I used blank r-xp space but just in case...
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, GamePID, (void *)(EMPTY_ADDR), (void *)save[0]) ||
        ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, GamePID, (void *)(EMPTY_ADDR + 8UL), (void *)save[1])) {
        printf(":: [Error] Cannot restore origcode.\n");
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, GamePID, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, GamePID, NULL, &oldregs)) {
        printf(":: [Error] Cannot restore registers.\n");
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, GamePID, NULL, NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    if (ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, GamePID, NULL, NULL)) {
        printf(":: [Error] Cannot detach from process.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("[+] Done.");
}
```

That's how my injector looks like. Strings and whatnot is hardcoded because this is dummy code. Here is /proc/pid/maps output:

```
08047000-08048000 rwxp 00000000 08:01 549662                             /home/bob/bin/game.orig
08048000-08125000 r-xp 00001000 08:01 549662                             /home/bob/bin/game.orig
08125000-08129000 rwxp 000dd000 08:01 549662                             /home/bob/bin/game.orig
08129000-0eb45000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
0f3e2000-14f10000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
c573f000-f7b69000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f7b6a000-f7b71000 rwxs 00000000 00:01 32821                              /SYSV0000271b (deleted)
f7b71000-f7b72000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f7bb5000-f7beb000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f7bec000-f7d3e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f7d3e000-f7e57000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1041510                            /home/bob/lib/libc.so.6
f7e57000-f7e59000 r-xp 00119000 08:01 1041510                            /home/bob/lib/libc.so.6
f7e59000-f7e5b000 rwxp 0011b000 08:01 1041510                            /home/bob/lib/libc.so.6
f7e5b000-f7e5d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f7e5d000-f7e66000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1041511                            /home/bob/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
f7e66000-f7e67000 rwxp 00009000 08:01 1041511                            /home/bob/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
f7e67000-f7e68000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f7e68000-f7e8c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1041512                            /home/bob/lib/libm.so.6
f7e8c000-f7e8d000 r-xp 00023000 08:01 1041512                            /home/bob/lib/libm.so.6
f7e8d000-f7e8e000 rwxp 00024000 08:01 1041512                            /home/bob/lib/libm.so.6
f7e8e000-f7f3d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1041514                            /home/bob/lib/libstdc++.so.5
f7f3d000-f7f42000 rwxp 000ae000 08:01 1041514                            /home/bob/lib/libstdc++.so.5
f7f42000-f7f47000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f7f47000-f7f56000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1041513                            /home/bob/lib/libpthread.so.0
f7f56000-f7f57000 r-xp 0000e000 08:01 1041513                            /home/bob/lib/libpthread.so.0
f7f57000-f7f58000 rwxp 0000f000 08:01 1041513                            /home/bob/lib/libpthread.so.0
f7f58000-f7f9b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
f7f9b000-f7f9e000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vvar]
f7f9e000-f7f9f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vdso]
f7f9f000-f7fb8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1041509                            /home/bob/lib/ld-linux.so.2
f7fb8000-f7fb9000 r-xp 00018000 08:01 1041509                            /home/bob/lib/ld-linux.so.2
f7fb9000-f7fba000 rwxp 00019000 08:01 1041509                            /home/bob/lib/ld-linux.so.2
ff000000-ff001000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
ff001000-ff200000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
ff200000-ff201000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
ff201000-ff400000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
ff400000-ff401000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
ff401000-ff600000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
ff600000-ff601000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
ff601000-ff800000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
fff4b000-fffa2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack]
```

My server spawns each thread as an independent process, and as you can see I had to use my libraries (/home/bob/lib) copied from and ancient RedHat version which was compatible with the threading model (getpid() returns a different value for each thread).

I would really like to hear some suggestions on how I can inject new code. Is it just as hacky as writing directly to /proc/pid/mem? How would I override a game function (say, HandlePlayerMove) with /proc/pid/mem? Is it possible to inject a shared object using LD_PRELOAD given that it was compiled against a newer version of libc, libm, etc? Is there a way of knowing what's triggering SIGSEGV without ptrace failing?

edit: dummy code typo

Comment: What about "disassembling it" and patching it at that level? You could also try "decompiling" it into C code which is a lot easier to work with, even if it will be littered with wonky, stupid variable names that make no sense before you clean them up.

Comment: Is LinuxThreads _statically_ linked into the server binary? Or, does it expect a `.so` that has the LinuxThreads function? What is the output of `ldd ./gameserver`. And, what about `nm ./gameserver` or `readelf -a ./gameserver`? If statically bound, you could _patch_ the executable [a copy!] with a hex editor and put (for every LinuxThreads function) (e.g.) `foo: jmp new_foo`. Then, you don't need to use `ptrace` for the patching. You just create a new `.so` that has glue code that works (e.g.) it has `new_foo` in it and that function does whatever is needed to make it work.

Comment: If you're dynamically bound, yes, probably `LD_PRELOAD` can do the job [easily].

Comment: @CraigEstey file ./game.server outputs `game.orig: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter ../lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, with debug_info, not stripped` . However when ldd'ing it I get `not a dynamic executable`. I assume it's dynamically linked since I was able to patchelf it and load my copied libraries from an older linux distro.

Comment: @CraigEstey I think patching the entire LinuxThreads architecture would be too much work, or maybe not possible at all (you would need a socket flag called F_SETOWN_EX which is only present in newer linux distros). And I not only want to tweak libc calls or shared library calls. I want to be able to override the game's internal functions to execute my own.

Comment: Based on `file` output, the file _is_ dynamic. But, the ELF interpreter is: `../lib/ld-linux.so.2`. On my system, I _have_ a `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` so a modern/compatible interpreter does exist. But, I'm not sure about the `../lib` part [usually it's full path]. That may be why `ldd` has trouble. It can't find the interp [which it needs]. `readelf -a` is your friend. It can tell you a lot of what `ldd` might. Also, `objdump --disassemble`.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can patch the first instruction of a given func you want to intercept (e.g.) `foo` to be `jmp new_foo`. Then, you write a `new_foo` and load it. When the existing program calls `foo`, it will jump to `new_foo` and you can do whatever you want. You just do this for any/all symbols you need to intercept. So, if you put these in (e.g.) `newlib.so`, you can use `patchelf` to add this library to the executable. In other words, you should be able to repeatedly patch the file until you intercept what you need. No need for `ptrace` or `/proc/pid/mem`

Comment: Also, look at the various `LD_*` environment variables. Controlling lazy evaluation by the interp can be useful. Also, `LD_DEBUG` can help. Disassembling/Decompiling can help. If only to help understand what/how you need to patch. `readelf -a` can tell you what libs the executable expects. Does it want a `glibc`? You have a full [not-stripped] symbol table. That helps.

Comment: @CraigEstey Will injecting a shared object work? Even if it's linked against new glibc, etc? And if that worked, can I simply declare pointers to game functions and call them from that injected code? That way I can use the server's own machinery to spawn threads and whatnot. I have debug symbols available for the server binary so finding specific. Is it necessary to compile in 32-bit mode?